# Devise access params in Devise sessions view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm on Rails 3.0.9, Ruby 1.9.2, Devise 1.3.4

URL to an authenticated Devise resource for my app, e.g.,

```
http://myblog.com/article/5?type=blah
```

This will cause Devise to redirect to a login page. I have a need on Devise login page, `sessions#new.html.erb`, to conditionally display a drop down depending on `type` and I have no idea how to access it from `sessions#new.html.erb`. I tried `params` and that didn't work, ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, Devise stores that info in a session variable

```
session[:user_return_to]
```

Hope this helps someone else out of a jam if they need to do the same thing